# Remove last occurrence of string in list

Tags: c#, linq

Is it possible to remove the last occurrence of a string from a list using Linq? Something like this:

```
var arr = "hello mom hello dad".Split(' ').ToList(); //hello mom hello dad
arr.RemoveLast(x => x.Contains("hello")); //hello mom dad
```

Basically remove the last occurrence of the list. I need to use [Contains](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx) on the string and it has to be a list.

Comment: `arr` is an array, not a list.  Also it really depends on if you want to remove from the existing list or create a new sequence, which is what Linq actually does.

Comment: @juharr My bad, I forgot to add `.ToList()` to my example.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Last occurrence.

Comment: @HenkHolterman 0 elements would remove nothing (obviously?), 1 element would remove that element, "hELLO" does not match "hello" so obviously that should not get removed.

Comment: And what about `"*hello*"` ? You did emphasize the `Contains()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
list.RemoveAt(list.FindLastIndex(x => x.Contains("hello")));
```

This above will remove last string that contains "hello" in it. If there's a possibility that none of the string items satisfies the search condition, and the code in that case should do nothing, then it's like this:

```
int index = list.FindLastIndex(x => x.Contains("hello"));
if (index != -1)
    list.RemoveAt(index);
```

Comment: Wow, never knew there was a `FindLastIndex` on List. Thanks!

Comment: Note this will throw an exception if none of the values in the list contain "hello".  Instead you should assign the result of `FindLastIndex` to a variable and check for -1 before calling `RemoveAt`.

Comment: @juharr Always check for IndexOutOfRange exceptions yep.

Answer (score 2):

The following will let you determine the index of the last item that contains "hello" and then remove it if one exists.  It uses C# 6 syntax.

```
var arr = "hello mom hello dad".Split(' ').ToList(); 
var removeIndex = arr.Select((s,i) => new { Value = s, Index = i })
                     .LastOrDefault(x => x.Value.Contains("hello"))
                     ?.Index;
if(removeIndex.HasValue)
    arr.RemoveAt(removeIndex.Value);
```

Answer (score -2):

Here's how to do it using lists:

```
var arr = "hello mom hello dad".Split(' ').ToList();
arr.RemoveAt(arr.LastIndexOf("hello"));
```

Comment: Not Linq but it does the job.

Comment: Why would you need LINQ for this?

Comment: I don't. Also it doesn't work with Contains, which I said it should.

Comment: @Blaatz0r Because my "hello" and the matched case is not always equal to, so I would have to check if my input is contained.

Comment: _I need to use Contains_